# Postman Cookie manager not sending Cookie

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, postman

I am using `v10.17.4` of postman. I am attempting to use the cookie manager to send cookies to `localhost` an example cookie is `authToken=06af9401-7997-456a-8995-cdf48bb40f3f; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 13 Sep 2024 14:26:39 GMT;` I have followed the documentation and set Path to / so that it works with all Paths and I have removed Secure so that it works with insecure http requests and the expiration date is in the future but the cookie is not beingh sent. The domain has also been whitelisted. Is there anything I am missing. Every other stackoverflow post on this issue mentions the Set-Cookie header which also doesn't seem to work or making sure to remove Secure from the Cookie.
I am sending the cookies to PHP Symfony both $_COOKIE and the cookies inside the request are empty. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is that I created the cookie for localhost but the URL was pointed towards 127.0.0.1 which meant that it wouldn't send the cookie.